# Atualizei a versão do laravel 5.2 para o 5.6 e estou tendo problemas nas requisições via ajax que recebe um retorno response()->json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

Tenho um sistema rodando normalmente no laravel 5.2, porém preciso de recursos que só tem nas versões mais atuais no framework.
Com isso realizei a atualização do mesmo para a versão 5.6 e estou tendo problemas nas requisições ajax que antes funciona normante no laravel 5.2.

## Script atualizado com as dicas dos colaboradores que responderam a essa pergunta .

```
<script>

        jQuery("form.form").submit(function () {
            var dados = jQuery(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url: jQuery("form.form").attr("action"),
                data: dados,
                success:function(data){
                    alert('Sucesso');
                },
                error:function(jqxhr, textStatus, err){
                  console.log(err);
                },
            });
            return false;
        });

</script>
```

## controller

```
public function Buscar()
{
    //caso eu retorno apenas uma string como abaixo, funciona normalmente e caí no 
    //método success
    return 'teste';

    //caso eu retorno um array json que é o que preciso  ele caí no método 
    //error com a seguinte mensagem SyntaxError: Unexpected token
    //in JSON at position 0
    //at parse (<anonymous>)


    return  response()->json(['pagina'=>'teste','result'=>'1']);
}
```

Obs: Em ambos os casos ao acompanhar no console do navegador os dados são retornados certinhos na guia 'network'

Conclusão, caso eu retorne uma string funciona normal, porém caso retorne uma array ele entra no error com a mensagem SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0
    at parse () no console, mais ainda assim ele da o retorno dos dados na guia network.

Comment: Ja tentou definir um dataType:"json" ??

Comment: Se ao acompanhar pelo console os dados estão chegando, o problema não seria na hora de manipular estes dados?

Comment: Quando você fazer o retorno de return  response()->json(['pagina'=>'teste','result'=>'1']); ele aparece no console na aba network?

Comment: sim , aparece corretamente na aba network, porém cai no método error do script , também já testei dataType:"json" .

Comment: Ficaria mais de identificar o erro caso você fizesse: `error:function(jqxhr, textStatus, err){ console.log(err); },`

Comment: Valdeir, seguindo sua dica obtive o erro mais detalhado, agora tenho esse retorno SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0
    at parse (<anonymous>)    , ai tentei acrescentar o token no array que retorno:  return  response()->json(['token'=>$token,'pagina'=>$p,'result'=>'1']);  essa variável $token é o valor do campo _token que é criado pelo laravel , pego ela corretamente no controller e adiciono ela no array na promiera posição, porém mesmo adicionando o token ele continua a dar o erro

Comment: Tenta isso no header

<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
E isso no script
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
</script>

Comment: tentei essa dica,continua dando o erro SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0
    at parse , traduzindo literalmente trata-se de um  Token inesperado no JSON na posição 0